# How do I make a temporary backup of the local datastore in the AppEngine SDK for MacOSX

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

How do I make a temporary backup of the local datastore in the AppEngine SDK for MacOSX

And where are the files located?

Answer (score 1):

Search for something called "local_db.bin" If you're using a plugin for Eclipse, you'll find this file in WEB-INF/appengine-generated

Answer (score 0):

`local_db.bin` is the database file and it is located in your project directory, just make a copy of it.