# appengine sdk clears datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, macos, google-cloud-datastore

I am having a slight problem with the appengine SDK.
When I close it, it clears the datastore.

It is a little annoying to create the test data/users every day, so any help would be great.

I am running OSX, just so you know. And I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734826/how-do-i-make-a-temporary-backup-of-the-local-datastore-in-the-appengine-sdk-for).

But I have no file anywhere on my machine with that name. Not even when the SDK is running and the datastore contains data.

The project is not set to clear datastore on startup and I can't see anything else relating to it in the settings.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Python SDK puts the datastore files in your system's temporary directory, thus the persistence of the datastore is not guaranteed. Provide a different path using the --datastore_path argument of dev_appserver.py.

Comment: Great, worked like a charm. Should anyone as clueless as myself, find this later. You can also set this flag in the SDK GUI under info.